# jQuery replace and add new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following HTML

```
 <tbody class="t_bdy">
          <tr class="Quotation_List_td">
            <td class="item"><a class="button2 crm_insert" href="#">Insert</a><a class="button2 crm_delta" href="#">Delete</a></td>
            <td class="Quotation_List_ItemTD description">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="quantitiy">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="unit_price">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="discount">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="total">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="Quotation_List_td">
            <td class="item"><a class="button2 crm_insert" href="#">Insert</a><a class="button2 crm_delta" href="#">Delete</a></td>
            <td class="Quotation_List_ItemTD description">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="quantitiy">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="unit_price">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="discount">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="total">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>



        </tbody>
```

I need to insert new `<tr>` when I click on button with  `.crm_insert` class.

When `.crm_insert`is clicked, it need to insert a new row at the current location. All
other rows will move down. For example, if insert against row 3 is clicked then
row 3 will be new row inserted and current row 3 etc will move down to become
row 4 etc.

How can  I achieve this ?

**All answers are good, but I can only accept one : Thanks all**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$('.crm_insert').live('click', function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.parents('tr.Quotation_List_td').before('add your row here');
});
```

The latest versions of jquery employ `on` instead of `live`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this using *closest()* and *before()*

```
$('a.crm_insert')
   .click(function()
    {$(this).closest('tr.Quotation_List_td').before(htmlcodeofyounewTRhere);}
    )
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- Your new row is in the same structure as your current row
- You want the new row to also have the 'Insert' functionality

You want a click event handler which does something to this effect:

```
$('.crm_insert', '#table').on('click', function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    currentRow.clone(true).insertBefore(currentRow);
});
```

Where `#table` is the id of your table.

[Here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/hThTB/1/)

If you are inserting something completely different, then you do not need to use `on()` or `clone()`, and the code becomes simpler:

```
$('.crm_insert').click(function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('<tr />').insertBefore(currentRow);
});
```

Where `<tr />` would be whatever you are trying to insert.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you. It'll find the parent tr of the button you just clicked, clone it (including the onClick functionality of the button) and insert that before the parent tr. This will result in a new row containing the same information as the target row though. Depending on what results you want to show in the new row, you might want to alter the code to clear out any copied values too.

```
$(".crm_insert").live("click", function(){
  var tr = $(this).parents("tr.Quotation_List_td"); 
  tr.clone().insertBefore(tr);
});
```